# click link with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, click

I have a link on my page that id like to click with the below javascript function, but it isnt working.  What I am really trying to do is use php to echo out a preclicked link.  I think I have used the right function $(selector).click(), but I dont know where to put the link.  I dont want to echo out the link, just the alert message.  The link is actually a thickbox alert message, that is only able to be clicked on.  I was hoping that i could use the .click() to activate it via php.  thanks

```
<?php
echo "
<script type='text/javascript'>$('#link').click();</script>
<a href='wronginput.php?height=40&width=80' id='link' class='thickbox'>Link text</a>";
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

At the time you output the javascript snippet, the link has not yet been parsed into the DOM, so `$('#link')` returns a null object. Either wrap it in a `.ready()` call, or place the javascript AFTER the link in your output.

```
<script>$(document).ready( function() { $('#link').click(); });</script>
<a href=...>
```

or

```
<a href=...>
<script...>
```

Comment: im sorry i am noob but how should i display the link? if i echo it out the user sees it.   If i include in html the user sees it as well. Im trying to keep the link hidden

Comment: Instead of outputting a link, look at what thickbox attaches to the link and trigger that function directly. Mostlikely thickbox has a function you can call rather than going the roundabound method of spitting out a link and "clicking" it.

Answer (score 0):

as Marc B said

```
<?php
echo "<a href='wronginput.php?height=40&width=80' id='link' class='thickbox'>Link text</a>
<script type='text/javascript'>$('#link').click();</script>
";
?>
```

or

```
<?php
echo "<script>$(document).ready( function() { $('#link').click(); });</script>
<a href='wronginput.php?height=40&width=80' id='link' class='thickbox'>Link text</a>   
";
?>
```